# JQuery combine IP address and time function

Tags: jquery, function, datetime, ip

Not sure how to do this but I am "calling" the ip address of users like this:

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",function(jsonResult){
alert(jsonResult.ip);
});
```

What I would like to do is "combine" the ip address no .'s with the time `new Date().getTime();` so I can get a "unique" number string.  Any suggestions?

Comment: there are better ways to get a unique number..!

Comment: For instance: `var rnd = ~~(Math.random() * (+new Date()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use something like this for generating a random number?

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999)
```

This will give you a random number between 0 and 99999

from: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/randomnum.shtml